# How to add to array from method in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm having a weird proplem that I can't understand

I have a registration form, and on any input I'm executing the method on blur;

```html
<input class='form-control' placeholder='Username' @blur="watchVal" v-model="username">
```

Method

```js
watchVal : function(){
  if(this.username == ""){
    this.errors['username'].push('Username is empty');
  }
}
```

Data:

```js
data: function(){
  return {
    username: "",
    errors: {
      'username' : []
    }
  }
}
```

When I blur without writing any value, nothing is added to `this.errors['username']`, unless I type a letter in any field.

I've also tried to make validation on submit, but found same problem that no error is added to the array unless I type in any input,

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong??

Comment: have you tried chrome dev tool for debug?

Comment: @ShahadatHossain Yep I'm using it for debugging

Comment: I mean after blur your input, have you seen that errors.username data update or not?

Comment: @ShahadatHossain Yes , It doesn't update until I write in any input

Comment: see my solution. I think it will solve

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue. How I solved this.

your data:

```
data: function(){
return {
  username: "",
  errors: {}
  }
}
```

your Method

```
watchVal (key) {
  let errors = this.errors
  if (this[key] === '') {
    errors[key].push('Emai empty')
  }

  this.errors = errors
}
```

your HTML

```
<input class='form-control' placeholder='Username' @blur="watchVal('username')" v-model="username">
<p>{{errors['username']}}</p>
```

You must display error variable in your HTML template then it will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your source is working. See in full mode if you cannot see error messages.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
   return {
     username: '',
      errors: {
       username: []
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
   watchVal : function(){
    if(this.username == ""){
      this.errors['username'].push('Username is empty');
    }
  }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input class='form-control' placeholder='Username' @blur="watchVal" v-model="username">
  <p class="text-sm text-danger" v-for="(error, index) in errors.username" :key="index">
    {{ error }}
  </p>
</div>
```